# What is the significance of "despotes" in Rev 6v10?

Tags: word-study

In Revelation "kyrios" is used some 21 times e.g. Rev 16v7. It is mostly translated "lord". In the N.K.J.V. in Rev 6v10 a word is also translated "lord" but this time it is "despotes" not "kyrios". Kyrios is well established [21 times] so is there some special significance to the only time that despotes is used in Revelation?

Comment: Cf. Jude 1:4, "our only Sovereign/Master [Gk. *despotes*] and Lord, Jesus Christ."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thayer has an interesting comment to make about the difference between the two words :

> I Tim 6:1, II Timothy 2:21, Titus 2:9, I Pet 2:18 .... God is thus addressed '*despotes*' by one who calls himself '*doulos*' (a bondman).
>
> Christ is called '*despotes*' as one who has bought (sic, I would say 'redeemed) his servants II Peter 2:1.
>
> Jude 4 refers to the One (some take it as God) who rules over the church and whose prerogative it is to take vengeance on those who persecute his followers.

Thayer further comments on the correlation between *despotes* and *doulos* in regard to absolute ownership and uncontrolled power. He says that *kurios* had a wider meaning applicable to the various ranks and relations of life, being not suggestive of either property or absolutism.

It seems to me that Thayer is saying that *kurios* is an aspect of personal relationship whilst *despotes* is a matter of rule and power.

Reference : Joseph H Thayer 4th edition 1896.

Answer (score 1):

The word δεσπότης (despotés) occurs about 10 times in the GNT and is used as a title for Jesus/Messiah/God in these places: Luke 2:29 ("Lord's Christ"), Acts 4:24, 2 Tim 2:21, Jude 4, Rev 6:10.  In the other instances, it refers to an earthly person such as a slave owner or master of the household.  Jude 4 is significant as both despotes and kyrios occur together.

The word kyrios is (as the OP correctly notes) frequently used as title for Jesus but it also used as a title for earthly humans as well.

The meaning of these two words clearly overlaps significantly.  BDAG describes δεσπότης (despotés) as meaning:

- **One who has legal control and authority over persons such as subjects or slaves, *lord, master***, or,
- **One who controls a thing, *owner*** of a vessel 2 Tim 2:21.

Thus, δεσπότης (despotés) is an entirely expected title for Jesus.

In the LXX "kyrios" is used to translate the tetragrammaton "YHWH" and so when used as a title for Jesus, carried this extra baggage/connotation of meaning, that is, supreme God.  By contrast "despotes" has the meaning of "master".  Clearly, the NT depicts Jesus in both these capacities as Jude 4 makes clear.

Comment: Trench "Synonyms of the N.T." and yourself are clear on general principles re: kyrios and despotes. I am still trying to see how these generalities apply to this specific verse.